# What's the best material for making knots?

Tags: knot-theory

Just a week ago I started to study knot theory.
I have been using copper wire to make knots, but it is too hard and sharp.
Strings are so soft that they cannot maintain their shapes. It's difficult to put string knots up.
What else can I use to make knots?

Comment: Clay. Or Play-do.

Comment: I've been recently using a 1/8" diamond braid nylon rope with a core.  It maintains its shape somewhat.

Comment: Pipe cleaners?${}$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that copper wires comes in smaller diameters and colors... Just purchase a different diameter 14AWG (1.63mm dia), 16AWG (1.29mm dia) solid (not stranded) wire, with some of your favourite colours: white (positive orientation), red (negative orientation), green, black, blue, and you would have a lot of fun.